# is it possible to set the height of density Bar inc UWP CalendarView

Tags: uwp

I am wondering, if it's possible to set the height of density Bar in a UWP CalendarView control?

Kind regards,

Martin

Answer (score 1):

The calendar grid of a [CalendarView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview) control is composed of [CalendarViewDayItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarviewdayitem) objects. We can modify the day item in the [CalendarViewDayItemChanging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview.calendarviewdayitemchanging) event of the [CalendarView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview) control using the `Item` property of the `CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs` to access the CalendarViewDayItem object. The **density Bar** is in the [CalendarViewDayItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarviewdayitem).

But to improve performance, the visual elements of a [CalendarViewDayItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarviewdayitem) are rendered directly by the control, not defined in the control template as XAML elements. This means we can’t style or re-template these elements. Even though there are several "calendar item" and "day item" properties that we can use to customize these elements, they don't have a property to set the height of the **density Bar**. So we can not modify the style to change the **density Bar**'s height.

So base on your requirement, we can do some alternative workarounds.

If you just think one density Bar is not well marked, you can provide two or more density Bars with colors to make it more obvious.

```
private void CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
{
            List<Color> densityColors = new List<Color>();
            densityColors.Add(Colors.Green);
            densityColors.Add(Colors.Green);
            args.Item.SetDensityColors(densityColors);
}
```

The another way would be more complicated. since the default Style (see [CalendarViewDayItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarviewdayitem) styles and template) also includes an empty `ControlTemplate` that you can use to inject custom XAML elements into the [CalendarViewDayItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarviewdayitem). Your XAML elements are rendered on top of the background elements, and below the day number and labels. So you can custom a  CalendarView and change `CalendarViewDayItem` style to add a "density Bar", meanwhile you should expose a property to control whether the "density Bar" is visible.

Here is a example style to add a "density Bar" to `CalendarViewDayItem`, you can put it in the page's resource to see the effect.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!-- Default style for CalendarViewDayItem -->
    <Style TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0, 0, 0,0" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-2" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem">
                    <!-- For CalendarViewDayItem, TextBlock visual is created and handled by code and we can't see it from the style. -->
                    <!-- CCalendarViewBaseItemChrome creates and appends a TextBlock in the visual after the ControlTemplate is applied -->
                    <!-- VSM needs a container and that's why Grid is added. But we don't need the rendering of Grid so We set width to 0 -->
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Width="40" Height="8" Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```